# How can I resize and crop/letterbox image to completely fill div with image whatever resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I need:

- The image must completely fill 100% the area the div covers - left to
  right and top to bottom.
- the image must not be squashed or streched -    just be cropped or
  must overflow.
- The image must be kept as small as possible, so whatever the resize - you
  can still see either the very sides OR the very top and bottom.

The div itself will be adjusting in height and width as both are a percentage of the main window.

I have found a little bit of JavaScript here that is manipulating the image just how I want when the window is resized, but is displaying it in the whole window.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>test</title> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function resizeImage() 
{ 
    var window_height = document.body.clientHeight 
    var window_width  = document.body.clientWidth 
    var image_width   = document.images[0].width 
    var image_height  = document.images[0].height 
    var height_ratio  = image_height / window_height 
    var width_ratio   = image_width / window_width 
    if (height_ratio > width_ratio) 
    { 
        document.images[0].style.width  = "100%" 
        document.images[0].style.height = "auto" 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        document.images[0].style.width  = "auto" 
        document.images[0].style.height = "100%" 
    } 
} 
</script> 

</head> 

<body onresize="resizeImage()"> 

<img onload="resizeImage()" src="f/a.jpg">   

</body> 
</html>
```

[Here is a demo](http://generationsinc.co.uk/test/java.html)

Please don't just answer that all I need is:

```
<img style="width : 100%;">
```

This is so much more than that.

It's not too easy to explain but check the demo and drag the corner of the window around and that'll be worth 1000 words...!

Can it (or something like it) be made to work the same way within a % sized div?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a jQuery plugin that does exactly this. Check out my blog post [here](https://christianvarga.com/jquery-resize-image-to-parent-container-plugin/) and the demo [here](http://www.christianvarga.com/demos/jQuery/resizeToParent/)

```
jQuery.fn.resizeToParent = function(options) {
  var defaults = {
   parent: 'div'
  }

  var options = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);

  return this.each(function() {
    var o = options;
    var obj = jQuery(this);

    // bind to load of image
    obj.load(function() {
      // dimensions of the parent
      var parentWidth = obj.parents(o.parent).width();
      var parentHeight = obj.parents(o.parent).height();

      // dimensions of the image
      var imageWidth = obj.width();
      var imageHeight = obj.height();

      // step 1 - calculate the percentage difference between image width and container width
      var diff = imageWidth / parentWidth;

      // step 2 - if height divided by difference is smaller than container height, resize by height. otherwise resize by width
      if ((imageHeight / diff) < parentHeight) {
       obj.css({'width': 'auto', 'height': parentHeight});

       // set image variables to new dimensions
       imageWidth = imageWidth / (imageHeight / parentHeight);
       imageHeight = parentHeight;
      }
      else {
       obj.css({'height': 'auto', 'width': parentWidth});

       // set image variables to new dimensions
       imageWidth = parentWidth;
       imageHeight = imageHeight / diff;
      }

      // step 3 - center image in container
      var leftOffset = (imageWidth - parentWidth) / -2;
      var topOffset = (imageHeight - parentHeight) / -2;

      obj.css({'left': leftOffset, 'top': topOffset});
    });

    // force ie to run the load function if the image is cached
    if (this.complete) {
      obj.trigger('load');
    }
  });
}
```

And if you want the image to resize when the window is resized, just bind a resize handler to the window:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('img').resizeToParent();
});
```

Comment: this is very close i have pulled the whole script in of your demo popped my own images in, changed the positions to absolute and the sizes to percentages and it works... almost. i have to hit refresh after resizing the window to get the images to resize - sorry i cant wright java but i think that a little onresize willcrack it.thanks so much for this

Comment: @Wellie Java is not ECMAScript (Javascript)

Comment: christian, what i really like about you script is that the letter box centers the image. when the div is very tall or very flat you dont just get the top or the left hand side you actually view a strip down the center - a much better way!

Comment: Christian, just another little snag, sorry, the images dont resize at all in my IE9 on 7 pro do you have any recomendations for this, Thanks very much.

Comment: I've edited the script to add ie9 compatibility, and showed a snippet of how to bind the image to resize when the window is resized.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've been playing around with it:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>


<style>

#imgarea {
position:absolute;
right:0px;
height:75%;
width:70%;
top:25%;
}

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

function resizeImage()
{
    var window_height = document.body.clientHeight
    var window_width  = document.body.clientWidth
    var image_width   = document.images[0].width
    var image_height  = document.images[0].height
    var area_width    = window_width * 0.7
    var area_height   = window_height * 0.75
    var height_ratio  = image_height / area_height
    var width_ratio   = image_width / area_width

    if (height_ratio > width_ratio)
    {
        document.images[0].style.width  = "100%"
        document.images[0].style.height = "auto"

    }
    else
    {
        document.images[0].style.width  = "auto"
        document.images[0].style.height = "100%"

    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body onresize="resizeImage()">
    <div id="imgarea">  
<img onload="resizeImage()" src="f/a.jpg">  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

- It keeps resizing as the div resizes - as mentioned the div is
  resizing with the window - this one keeps working seemlesly.
- It seems to be OK across IE9, Fire Fox, Oprea, Chrome, and safari
  over xp and 7

so really it answers my question perfectly, its just - now i've seen Christian's centering version i wish i had the know-how to make this do it i've tried a few things but am now stuck. Any Ideas?

P.S. if you dont know the width and height % of the div when you right the script i think it could be got with GetElementById - somehow... beyond me though;)